# Implement java collection without losing information

Tags: java, collections

I have a class that contains two attributes :

```
@lombok.Data
public class BusinessObjectCollection<T> implements Serializable {
    protected List<T> elements;
    protected Integer totalCount;
    public BusinessObjectCollection() {
        this.elements = new ArrayList<>();
        this.totalCount = 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

I want this class to implements the interface java.util.Collection in order to call remove(), addAll(), and some other methods directly on the BusinessObjectCollection objet.

So I modify my class like this :

```
@lombok.Data
public class BusinessObjectCollection<T> implements Collection<T>, Serializable{
    protected List<T> elements;
    protected Integer totalCount;
    public BusinessObjectCollection() {
        this.elements = new ArrayList<>();
        this.totalCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return elements.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return elements.removeAll(c);
    }

    [...]
}
```

My problem is that if I do this, my object lose some informations. I can't see the "elements" and "totalCount" attributes.

[image]

Is it possible to use the Collection interface and keep this attributes ?

If no, is there a good alternative ?

Comment: This seems to be a feature in your debugger. Whenever it encounters a collection, it will show you the elements instead of the real data. This is very useful for the more complex collections (think HashSet) because when debugging those classes you are interested in the contents, and how they are used in your code, but not so much in the inner workings. So the answer to this will depend on what IDE you use (and thus what debugger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are viewing a feature in your IDE. In your case probably IntelliJ.

When it encounters a `Collection`, it will only show the contents of the collection and not the actual implementation. This is very useful most of the time, because you are using Collections that might have very complex structures, such as `HashSet`. But when developing your own collection, you want to see that actual workings in the debugger.

In IntelliJ this is called 'Alternative view for Collection classes'. The [manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/customize-data-views.html) explains how to disable this.

In Eclipse this is also available (but seems to be turned off by default). The feature is called Logical Structures. This view can be enabled with a toggle button ('Show Logical Structure') in the Variables View.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there was this setting.